# Insert specific number of rows in a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to insert a specific number of cells into a Google sheet based on a number that is saved as a range. For example, the number in the range is 52, so on sheet 'Master' I want to insert 52 rows after row A3. This range is found on the sheet 'Staff' and changes according to how many staff were present each day, therefore, making it dynamic.

I am looking for some gscript to do this.  I have been able to do this using a macro in Excel VBA but would like to move this from Excel to Google Sheets. The VBA code looks like this:

```
Sheets("Master").Select
  Range("A3").EntireRow.Resize(Range("staff_count").Value).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
```

Would be very grateful if anyone could help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to insert a given number of rows after row 3 on "Master". The number of rows is the value of a range on another sheet "Staff". This value will change from day to day.

In the following example, the range on Staff is cell "B1" and its value is 52.

There are several methods of doing this. In this example, I've used `insertRowsAfter(afterPosition, howMany)`[doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsafterafterposition,-howmany). However, you could also use `insertRows(rowIndex, numRows)` [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsrowindex,-numrows).

---

```
function so5910073802() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var mastersheetname = "Master";
  var master = ss.getSheetByName(mastersheetname);

  var staffsheetname = "Staff";
  var staff = ss.getSheetByName(staffsheetname);

  // Staff range and value
  var staffAttendRange = staff.getRange("B1");
  var staffAttendValue = staffAttendRange.getValue(); // value = 52
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Staff attendance = "+staffAttendValue);

  // Master variables
  var headerRows = 3;

  // insert the rows on Master based on value from Staff
  master.insertRowsAfter(headerRows, staffAttendValue);

}
```

---

**Before vs After**

The value on row 4 and row 56 is `=row()`

**BEFORE**
[image: Before]

**AFTER**
[image: After]

Comment: Isn't the number of rows needs to be selected from the 'Staff' sheet?

Comment: Yikes, you're absolutely right!!. Thanks. Answer edited.

Comment: Thank you very much for that, it is excellent and looks simple when you know. Appreciate that.